# What is the difference between on_press and on_release in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I need to know what is the difference between on_press and on_release in kivy and python button

Comment: A button can be pressed and released again.

Comment: [Simple explanation from kivy docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_press` triggers only when you **press** the button. On the other hand, `on_release` fires only when you **release** the button. This link from the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/) that was sent in the comments should help: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html